# How do I skip / jump past next string instance selection in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Whilst running the hotkey for multiple cursors  <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> I keep finding myself in need of skipping only one item.

So for instance, in the following code, pipes indicate my current selection and the item in the middle I would like to skip.

```
 checked=""| 
 checked=""| 
 checked=""| 
 checked=""| // <-- I am here in my selection
 checked=""  // <-- skip this item for selection and proceed to select the rest
 checked=""
 checked=""
 checked=""
```

Is this doable in VSCode?

What have I tried so far?

I have tried using <kbd>shift</kbd> and looking up the [VSCode shortcuts documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+d",
  "command": "editor.action.moveSelectionToNextFindMatch",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

This keybinding is already there.  You actually select the one you want to skip and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to move that last selection you did to the next find match.

Or, just select them all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>and then go back with your multicursor modifier key <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> and deselect the ones you don't want one by one.

Here is a demo of both methods - the gif doesn't show all the keystrokes very well unfortunately - the skip one is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as explained above **after** you have selected one too many:

[image: demo of skipping find matches]

Comment: Deselection in the 2nd case works only for me when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> alone. If I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> it doesn't work #mac

Comment: @hashier Yes, that is right.  You use whatever you have your multicursor modifier key set to : `Cmd` or `Alt` - not both.  I intended `Cmd`/`Alt` to indicate the alternative not both.  Sorry for the confusion.